# change date format in displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this below code where i am trying to alert the date selected on click of an image. I am getting the alert but the issue is date format.

Below is alert i am getting. I need the alert in mm/dd/yyy.

And also why i am getting Thu Jan 01 1970 if i use todatestring() method.

Below is the javascript code

Comment: What's your intent in the addition of the two dates?

Comment: From input tag i am displaying the dates in a div tag container. In the code u can see image after clicking i need to display those dates in input tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function to return mm/dd/yyyy

```
function getmmDdYy(thisDate) {
        return ('0' + (thisDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
            '/' +
            ("0" + (thisDate.getDate())).slice(-2) +
            '/' +
            thisDate.getFullYear();
    }
```

So on your `fnUpdateDate()`, do this:

```
function fnUpdateDate(date1,date2){
alert(getmmDdYy(new Date(date1)) +" ss "+ getmmDdYy(new Date(date2)));
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hi Ross I am geting 01/01/1970 ss 01/01/1970

Comment: Isn't that what you want?  the format to be in mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: I am not getting wht i am selecting in input date tag...if i am selecting todays date i am getting 01/01/1970.. And if i display only date1 value its coming as  
Date1 = 0.0002610693400167084

Comment: Your question was about the date format.  You may want to check what these value return to you:

`var a = document.getElementById("page:j_id1:myPicker1").value;
var a1 = document.getElementById("page:j_id1:myPicker2").value;`

This is where the date is getting set to '01/01/1970'

Comment: I am getting 10/12/2016 as i am selecting the same.. which is correct..

Comment: I see your error now, change this:

`str+="<a href='#' onclick='fnUpdateDate("+a+","+a1+")'>";`

to this:

`str+="<a href='#' onclick=\"fnUpdateDate('"+a+"','"+a1+"')\">";`

let me know if it works.

You were passing an object instead of a string.

Comment: in browser console i am seeing ....<div class="label" date1="10/4/2016" date2="10/12/2016">1. Date 1 10/4/2016Date 2 10/12/2016<a href="#" onclick="fnUpdateDate(10/4/2016,10/12/2016)"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQlvCNq-gyHx63VKBLy1H-lHnqRar0jKJqkoCP9giVm5y76NVY-jg" width="48" height="48"></a></div>

Comment: but not sure why alert is showing something different

Comment: this part is wrong: `onclick="fnUpdateDate(10/4/2016,10/12/2016)"` you are passing an object instead of a string.  the correct one is: `onclick="fnUpdateDate('10/4/2016','10/12/2016')"` See the single quotes around the dates?

Comment: Again, change it to this and try: `str+="<a href='#' onclick=\"fnUpdateDate('"+a+"','"+a1+"')\">";`

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the single components from a date (day, month, year) and build a string with them (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30272803).

If you add the library moment.js you will be able to use formatting strings like `YYYYMMDD` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27635223).

Answer (score 0):

```
You can pass your date to this function and return the formate as per your need

function formatDate(date) {
                        var d = new Date(date),
                         month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
                         day = '' + d.getDate(),
                         year = d.getFullYear();
                         if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
                         if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
                         return (month+"/"+day+"/"+year);  
                    }
```